# Passing variable from block within including template

Tags: include, blocks

I have this situation, where variable `param` doesn't exist.

**skeleton.twig**

```
{# Inject template #}
{% block var %}{% endblock %} 
{% include '_includes/template' %}
```

Now I want to extends **index.twig** with skeleton.twig and output all rendered data.

```
{% extends "skeleton" %}

{% block var %}
    {# Set parameter #}
    {% set param = {
        section: ['handle1', 'handle2']
    } %}
{% endblock %}
```

**template.twig**

```
{% paginate craft.entries(param) as entriesOnPage %}
    {# data #}
{% endpaginate %}
```

As I go step by step in rendering process, I think, that the reason Why I'm getting this problem is because, the ECM is printed after `{% include '_includes/components/feed/feed' %}`.

Otherwise I have no idea, except I put wrong `craft.entries(param)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that is defined in `index.twig` outside of a `block` will be available in `skeleton.twig`, and so also in `template.twig`. This should work:

**skeleton.twig**

```
{% include '_includes/template' %}
```

**index.twig**

```
{% extends "skeleton" %}

{# Set parameter #}
{% set param = {
    section: ['handle1', 'handle2']
} %}
```